# How can I calculate GCD of really large BigInteger numbers without getting a stackoverflow exception?

Tags: java, stack-overflow, biginteger, greatest-common-divisor

I implemented my own Class Fraction, where I have a BigInteger numerator object and BigInteger denominator object. Whenever I call the constructor of a Fraction object, it parses the numerator and denominator from the argument and simplifies the fraction. The problem I am having is that I am getting stack overflow exception when calling gcd(biginteger numerator, biginteger denominator) for really big numbers. I want to be able to get the gcd of really big BigInteger objects.

```
private BigInteger gcd(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
{
        if(a.mod(b).toString().equals("0"))
            return b;
        return gcd(b, a.mod(b));
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.math.MutableBigInteger.divideKnuth(MutableBigInteger.java:1203)
    at java.math.MutableBigInteger.divideKnuth(MutableBigInteger.java:1163)
    at java.math.BigInteger.remainderKnuth(BigInteger.java:2167)
    at java.math.BigInteger.remainder(BigInteger.java:2155)
    at java.math.BigInteger.mod(BigInteger.java:2460)
    at Fraction.Fraction.gcd(Fraction.java:69)
    at Fraction.Fraction.gcd(Fraction.java:71)
    at Fraction.Fraction.gcd(Fraction.java:71)
    at Fraction.Fraction.gcd(Fraction.java:71)
```

And A lot more of the Fraction.Fraction.gcd(Fraction.java:71).

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Replace recursion with loop. For example, see this: http://javaonlineguide.net/2015/02/java-code-to-find-greatest-common-divisor-gcd-using-recursion-loop.html

Comment: Using a loop would be better here I think.

Comment: There is an implementation of `gcd` in `BigInteger` yet. BTW.: You should compare to `BigInteger.ZERO` instead of comparing to a string.

Comment: And not compute `a.mod(b)` twice per invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have coded [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid's_algorithm) incorrectly.  The algorithm is this:

```
gcd(a, 0) = a
gcd(a, b) = gcd(b, a mod b)
```

That's not what your code does.

```
// This is supposed to implement the first term ... but it doesn't
if (a.mod(b).toString().equals("0"))
        return b;
```

---

The comments above by @clemens and @EJP are apropos.

The comment by @AlexF is only relevant for extremely large numbers.  Euclid's algorithm converges rapidly.  (See https://math2.uncc.edu/~frothe/Euclidextendpnew.pdf for the gory details.)